# Get all endpoints from axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I have wrote app in ReactJS and now I need get all endpoints which I used in axios. Someone know whether exists any method to get this information?

Or exists a clever method to do it?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to hit an endpoint that returns all available endpoints?

Comment: No, I would like get all urls which I wrote in axios.

Comment: do you use Visual Studio Code? on mine i do a gloval `find` for a keyword maybe in your case it would be something like `axios.`

Comment: Yes, but find almost 200 endpoints will be time-consuming and I would like do it automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex to find all your requests made with the `axios.methodName` This is providing that you have a string of you entire un-uglified/un-compiled source code. Alternatively, use the regex within VSCode (or another IDE that supports `find` by Regex) and find a way of extracting the results of as a String.

```js
const s = `
axios.get('hello/GET')
axios.put('hello/PUT/FOO')
axios.post('hello/PoSt/BAR/YO')
axios.delete('hello/delete/etc/etc')
axios.foo('hello/foo/foo/foo')
`

const matches = s.match(/(?!axios\.[A-z]+)(?:\([A-z\/'"]*\))/gm)

console.log(matches)
```